# Remove tabs and put everything on one line

Tags: notepad++

so I have a problem.

I'm currently using Notepad++ ; I have millions of lines of a text file that look like this:

abs[TAB]traz
make[TAB]one

---

How do I make it so that it's all on one line(or column, I'm not sure), i.e

---

abs

traz

make

one

Comment: the "abs[TAB]traz" and "make[TAB]one" are on different lines.

Answer (score 4):

go to Search menu, select Replace... (or press ctrl-h)

Find what: \t

Replace with: \n

Selected "Extended" search mode

click replace all

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. Also, how would I get rid of duplicates? i.e make every character unique? Such as there being 5 "asdf123" and I want there to be only 1.

Comment: you can try instructions here: http://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2012/05/16/notepad-remove-duplicates-remove-blank-lines-and-sort-data-in-one-operation/   but seems you need to install a plugin called TextFX , not sure if there is another way in notepad++